# Delphi xe5 fieldbyname turkye i uppercase

Tags: delphi-xe5, uppercase, turkish

I have a problem with the turkish i and capital I.

In turkye there is also a dotted capital I. When i send a fieldbyname with the lowercase i it will not find my field because in the background the functions capares it with the capital dotted I

Does anyone know a workaround?

These 2 lines of code has different results:

```
  showmessage(s.ToUpper);
  showmessage(uppercase(s));
```

The fieldbyname uses the 1st one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FieldByName finds a match by calling CompareText using the user's default locale, with case insensitivity.  CompareText is a function provided by Windows.

If CompareText is saying that lowercase-I, and capital-letter-I-with-dot don't match, then your choices are:

[1]  Use the capital dotted I in your call to FieldByName, or

[2]  Use a locale in which those two characters are treated the same by CompareText.